# Trying to install Imagemagick through Homebrew

Tags: imagemagick, homebrew

Trying to install Imagemagick through Homebrew and I'm getting the following errors when I run brew doctor:

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

```
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/curl-config
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/ncurses5-config
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/ncursesw5-config
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/pkg-config
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/xml2-config
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/xslt-config
```

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libical.0.0.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libicalss.0.0.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libicalvcal.0.0.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libltdl.3.1.0.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
    /usr/local/lib/libical.la
    /usr/local/lib/libicalss.la
    /usr/local/lib/libicalvcal.la
    /usr/local/lib/libltdl.la

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
    /usr/local/lib/libdevkit.a
    /usr/local/lib/libical.a
    /usr/local/lib/libicalss.a
    /usr/local/lib/libicalvcal.a
    /usr/local/lib/libkld.a
    /usr/local/lib/libltdl.a
    /usr/local/lib/libredo_prebinding.a

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either remove `/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin` from your `PATH` and/or remove the unbrewed libraries, or ignore the warnings if you know what you doing, and accept the potential consequences of mix-and-match builds.

These issues might not actually prevent you from building or installing anything.  They are just advice in case something does fail.

See also https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/17934, for instance.